# Matlab fitlm plotting the errorbars

Tags: matlab, error-handling, linear-regression, errorbar

I am using fitlm to fit a set of data and now I am trying to add the errorbars to my plot. 
Fist of all, the error obtained from fitlm is the one written out as "Root mean squared error"?! 
And if yes, how can I add this error as an errorbar to my plot?

mdl1 =

Linear regression model:
    y ~ 1 + x1

Estimated Coefficients:
                   Estimate       SE        tStat     pValue
                   ________    _________    ______    ______

```
(Intercept)    2.1999      0.0043976    500.25    0     
x1             591.68        0.31096    1902.8    0
```

Number of observations: 24800, Error degrees of freedom: 24798
Root Mean Squared Error: 0.693
R-squared: 0.993,  Adjusted R-Squared 0.993
F-statistic vs. constant model: 3.62e+06, p-value = 0

thanks

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand the problem. You got root square error, so why you can't add it using build-in function `errorbar` ?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks

Comment: If you figured it out please post the answer so others know! Give and recieve!